# Sending an Integer or String via bluetooth - the devices are paired already

Tags: android, string, sockets, bluetooth, integer

so i've been working on an application which allows me to send a simple string such as " Hello ", or integer such as  " 2 " through the bluetooth, i've already made the connection between the devices and they're both paired all i want to know is an example code of how to work with sockets and other stuffs that i need to send something through the app.

My code by far :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView mStatusTv;
private Button mActivateBtn;
private Button mPairedBtn;
private Button mScanBtn;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDlg;

private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mStatusTv           = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
    mActivateBtn        = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_enable);
    mPairedBtn          = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_view_paired);
    mScanBtn            = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);

    mBluetoothAdapter   = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    mProgressDlg        = new ProgressDialog(this);

    mProgressDlg.setMessage("Scanning...");
    mProgressDlg.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDlg.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
    });

    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        showUnsupported();
    } else {
        mPairedBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

                if (pairedDevices == null || pairedDevices.size() == 0) {
                    showToast("No Paired Devices Found");
                } else {
                    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> list = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

                    list.addAll(pairedDevices);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DevicelistActivity.class);

                    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("device.list", list);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        mScanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        });

        mActivateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

                    showDisabled();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
                }
            }
        });

        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            showEnabled();
        } else {
            showDisabled();
        }
    }

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
    }

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

    super.onDestroy();
}

private void showEnabled() {
    mStatusTv.setText("Bluetooth is On");


    mActivateBtn.setText("Disable");
    mActivateBtn.setEnabled(true);

    mPairedBtn.setEnabled(true);
    mScanBtn.setEnabled(true);
}

private void showDisabled() {
    mStatusTv.setText("Bluetooth is Off");


    mActivateBtn.setText("Enable");
    mActivateBtn.setEnabled(true);

    mPairedBtn.setEnabled(false);
    mScanBtn.setEnabled(false);
}

private void showUnsupported() {
    mStatusTv.setText("Bluetooth is unsupported by this device");

    mActivateBtn.setText("Enable");
    mActivateBtn.setEnabled(false);

    mPairedBtn.setEnabled(false);
    mScanBtn.setEnabled(false);
}

private void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
                showToast("Enabled");

                showEnabled();
            }
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
            mDeviceList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

            mProgressDlg.show();
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            mProgressDlg.dismiss();

            Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DevicelistActivity.class);

            newIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("device.list", mDeviceList);

            startActivity(newIntent);
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            mDeviceList.add(device);

            showToast("Found device " + device.getName());
        }
    }
};}
```

Device list :

```
public class DevicelistActivity extends Activity {
private ListView mListView;
private Adapter mAdapter;
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDeviceList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_devicelist);

    mDeviceList     = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("device.list");

    mListView       = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_paired);

    mAdapter        = new Adapter(this);

    mAdapter.setData(mDeviceList);
    mAdapter.setListener(new Adapter.OnPairButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPairButtonClick(int position) {
            BluetoothDevice device = mDeviceList.get(position);

            if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                unpairDevice(device);
            } else {
                showToast("Pairing...");

                pairDevice(device);
            }
        }
    });

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    registerReceiver(mPairReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mPairReceiver);

    super.onDestroy();
}


private void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void unpairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
        method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mPairReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            final int state         = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
            final int prevState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

            if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                showToast("Paired");


                Intent transmit = new Intent(DevicelistActivity.this,transmission.class);
                startActivity(transmit);



            } else if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                showToast("Unpaired");
            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};}
```

Adapter :

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter{
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<BluetoothDevice> mData;
private OnPairButtonClickListener mListener;



public Adapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void setData(List<BluetoothDevice> data) {
    mData = data;
}

public void setListener(OnPairButtonClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public int getCount() {
    return (mData == null) ? 0 : mData.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView         =  mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_adapter, null);

        holder              = new ViewHolder();

        holder.nameTv       = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        holder.addressTv    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        holder.pairBtn      = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_pair);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    BluetoothDevice device  = mData.get(position);

    holder.nameTv.setText(device.getName());
    holder.addressTv.setText(device.getAddress());
    holder.pairBtn.setText((device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) ? "Unpair" : "Pair");
    holder.pairBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onPairButtonClick(position);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameTv;
    TextView addressTv;
    TextView pairBtn;
}

public interface OnPairButtonClickListener {
    public abstract void onPairButtonClick(int position);
}
```

So as you see that i build an Intent at deviceList activity which moves me to a new activity which is supposed to have an edit text to be filled with the numbers or texts that are going to be sent to the paired device,

Please help me with the new activity i'm referring to, any codes or advices are really appreciated! thank you stackoverflow Community!

ps : the other device is not necessarily a phone, it can also be a micro AVR or arduino but that's not the issue, i just want to know how to work with connection and sending data, please prevent from sending google links cuz i've already searched alot and it was quite complicated!

Comment: I guess there are very few people in the android community who have actively worked on BT. I am stumbling around and figuring it as I go. Hope you made progress since asking your question.